# The Closed-form form of a very nice series

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

How to find the Closed-form of this series 
      $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{e^{2\pi n}-1}+\frac{1}{e^{\pi (2n-1)}+1} $$
I played with the second series and I got that 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{e^{\pi (2n-1)}+1}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sinh(\pi n)} $$
But I don't know what to do more

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @fishfag it's very useful and smart hint

Comment: Do you know modular forms and their particular values (at CM points) ? One starting point is to use the Poisson summation formula and that $1/\cosh(\pi x)$ is its own Fourier transform to show $f(x) =\sum_n 1/\cosh(\pi nx) = x^{-1} f(1/x)$ is a modular form of weight $1$ for $\Gamma_0(4),\chi_4$

Comment: For what it's worth, Mathematica gives me $$\frac{1}{e^{2 (2 n-1) \text{pi}}+1}+\frac{-\psi _{e^{-2 \pi }}^{(0)}(1)-\log \left(e^{-2 \pi } \left(e^{2 \pi }-1\right)\right)}{2 \pi }$$

Comment: @Math1000 As every modular form evaluated at CM point $u+iv, u,v,d\in \Bbb{Q}$ the series has a closed-form radical expression plus possibly some $\pi^a\Gamma(1/4)^b$ term

Comment: @reuns , I don't know actually what do you talk about , but what is it's closed-form according to your method